# Optimizing database query C# EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I am retrieving 40kbs of data from my backend by fetching this task with its related information. I tried to do this approach instead of the commented out code, since it took 5,6 seconds just to fetch that data.

The commented out code does in fact get all the data I need, but it seems like the uncommented code does not, even though to me it should be the same. Does anyone know a fix, or maybe an even faster approach than this?

```
   public Task GetTask(int taskId)
    {
        // return Context.Tasks
        //     .Include(a => a.Customer)
        //     .Include(a => a.Project)
        //     .Include(a => a.Person)
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskSubs.OrderBy(b => b.Done).ThenBy(b => b.Order))
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskStatus)
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskPriority)
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskEmployees.Where(b => b.Active == true))
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskComments.OrderByDescending(b => b.CreatedOn))
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskCommentCustomers.OrderByDescending(b => b.CreatedOn))
        //     .ThenInclude(b => b.Person)
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskAppointments.OrderByDescending(b => b.Appointment.Date).Where(a => a.Appointment.Active))
        //     .ThenInclude(b => b.Appointment)
        //     .Include(a => a.TaskProjectices)
        //     .ThenInclude(b => b.ProjectEx)
        //     .Single(a => a.TaskId == taskId);
        
        var task = Context.Tasks
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(a => a.Customer)
            .Include(a => a.Project)
            .Include(a => a.Person)
            .Include(a => a.TaskSubs)
            .Include(a => a.TaskStatus)
            .Include(a => a.TaskEmployees.Where(b => b.Active == true))
            .Include(a => a.TaskComments)
            .Include(a => a.TaskCommentCustomers)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.Person)
            .Include(a => a.TaskAppointments)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.Appointment)
            .Include(a => a.TaskProjectices)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.ProjectEx)
            .SingleOrDefault(a => a.TaskId == taskId);


        task.TaskComments = task.TaskComments.OrderByDescending(b => b.CreatedOn).ToList();
        task.TaskCommentCustomers = task.TaskCommentCustomers.OrderByDescending(b => b.CreatedOn).ToList();
        task.TaskAppointments = task.TaskAppointments.OrderByDescending(b => b.Appointment.Date).Where(a => a.Appointment.Active).ToList();
        task.TaskSubs = task.TaskSubs.OrderBy(b => b.Done).ThenBy(b => b.Order).ToList();
        
        return task;
    }
```

Comment: If you are asking about performance you should include relevant data, like number of rows, total bytes that are fetched, and ideally things like execution plans etc.

Comment: 1) Add `AsSplitQuery()` to your query 2) `OrderBy` you can use in `Include` body, so additional postprocessing is not needed.

Comment: What driver are you using in the connection string?  What type of Database? A database should be put on a machine that is the fastest you can get, with most memory, and largest number of cores.  The database should also be put on a fast disk that is not fragmented.  Most database support multiple type of drivers and some drivers are faster than others.  Using stored procedure can help speed up any filtering since the machine where database is located SHOULD be more powerful than most client machines.